# conversion of a binary put in a comp -3 field Cobol

Tags: binary, hex, cobol, comp-3

I am trying to convert a pic S9 (9)V99 comp-3 field which has been store with binary in it.  It is display like this:   6/PS   X'000000002000'.

This amount should show like this  20.00.    I am trying to find the proper way to convert it to a pic -9 (9)V99  field.

Thanks

Comment: The proper way is to create a formatted output picture  Something like PIC ---,---,--9.99.

Comment: If I move it to a 9(05) field it comes out like this  X'F0F0F0F0F2'.  It is not working with this picture display.

Comment: Without seeing your COBOL code, I don't see where the FFFFF comes from.  A move from a PIC S(9)V99 COMP-3 fields to a PIC 9(5) field should display 00020.  Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a place where I can tutor you in the finer points of COBOL PICTURE coding.  There are plenty of COBOL tutorials on the Internet.

Comment: I agree with you.  but the date in the field has been store as binary like I mentionned before as X'000000002000'  which is not matching with the definition S9(9)v99 COMP-3.  I am trying to find the proper way to extract this.  So gymnastic needs to be done to achieve this.

Comment: First of all, this is the first time you mentioned a date.  Second, what is X'000000002000' supposed to look like when displayed?  In your question,. you say 20.00.  So, for the gymnastics.  1) Convert X'000000002000' to X'00000002000C'.  I can't explain this conversion in a comment.  2) Convert X'00000002000C' to 20.00 using a move from PIC S9(9)V99 COMP-3 to PIC ---,---,--9.99.

Comment: It looks like basically the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37058303/decode-a-binary-coded-decimal/37060596#37060596 . Create comp-3 with an extra decimal digit do pic x redefines of both.

Comment: Is there a reason the value is in a variable declared as COMP-3? Why not just define the value as a binary numeric type to begin with? It won't be straightforward to work with a 6-byte hex value as binary numeric, but it should be more clear than trying to work with a COMP-3 variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is basically the same as [Decode a Binary Coded Decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37058303/decode-a-binary-coded-decimal/37060596#37060596)

You create a comp-3 with 1 more decimal digit and do 'pic x' moves.

```
  01  WS-AMT-IN                 PIC S9(009)V99  COMP-3.
  01  WS-AMT-IN-X  REDEFINES                 
      WS-AMT-IN                 PIC  X(006). 

  01  WS-AMT-OUT1               PIC S9(009)V999  COMP-3.
  01  REDEFINES  WS-AMT-OUT1               
      03 WS-AMT-OUT1-X          PIC  X(006).   
      03                        PIC  s9 comp-3 value zero.

 01  WS-AMT-OUT-2               PIC S9(009)V99  COMP-3.


  Move  X'000000002000'         to WS-AMT-IN-X  
  Move  WS-AMT-IN-X             to WS-AMT-OUT1-x 
  Move  WS-AMT-OUT1             to WS-AMT-OUT-2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I resolve it:

```
01 WS-ZONENUM11.                                
   05 WS-ZONE9NUM                  PIC 9(009).  
   05 WS-ZONE2NUM                  PIC 9(002).  
01 WS-ZONENUM11-RED    REDEFINES WS-ZONENUM11   
                                   PIC 9(09)V99.

01 WS-AMT-OUT                         PIC -9(009).99. 

01 WS0900-AMT-IN               COMP-3 PIC S9(009)V99.
01 WS0900-AMT-IN-RED  REDEFINES                 
         WS0900-AMT-IN                PIC  X(006).   


 MOVE WS0900-AMT-IN-RED         TO  WS-WS0900-AMT-IN.
 MOVE WS-ZONEX5NM               TO  WS-ZONE9NUM.          
 MOVE WS-ZONEX1NM               TO  WS-ZONE2NUM.          

 MOVE WS-ZONENUM11-RED          TO  WS-AMT-OUT.
```

WS-AMT-OUT  now is displayed as _00000020.00   where _ is the sign (the sign here will be always a blank since it was not in the binary amount field.

Comment: Where do you get WS0900-AMT-IN from? What compiler are you using? Why use the REDEFINES there? There is no need, and, strictly, you have overlapping fields and the result of that MOVE is "undefined", even though it may work on your particular compiler (it may no with another). You don't show a  definition of the ZONEX fields. Do you actually have a BCD, like in this recent question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37058303/1927206? Without answers, I really don't think your code is doing what you think it is doing.

Comment: The ws0900-amt-in is coming from another system (Tandem) maybe using TAL language, not sure.

Answer (score -2):

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. XYZ.
DATA DIVISION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01 WS-BIN PIC 9(10).
01 TEMP PIC Z(10).
01 EXP PIC 9(2) VALUE 0.
01 R1 PIC 9(10).
01 C PIC 9(10).
PROCEDURE DIVISION.

DISPLAY " ENTER THE BINARY NUMBER ".
ACCEPT WS-BIN.

PARA1.
DIVIDE WS-BIN BY 10 GIVING WS-BIN REMAINDER R1.
COMPUTE C = C + R1 * 2 ** EXP
ADD 1 TO EXP.
IF WS-BIN NOT = 0
GO TO PARA1
ELSE GO TO PARA2.
PARA2.

MOVE C TO TEMP
DISPLAY " THE DECIMAL NUMBER IS " TEMP.
STOP RUN.
```